# Adding intermediate observations to a data frame (manual interpolating)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I've got a data frame like below with vector coordinates:

```
df <- structure(list(x0 = c(22.6, 38.5, 73.7), y0 = c(62.9, 56.6, 27.7
), x1 = c(45.8, 49.3, 80.8), y1 = c(69.9, 21.9, 14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     x0    y0    x1    y1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  22.6  62.9  45.8  69.9
2  38.5  56.6  49.3  21.9
3  73.7  27.7  80.8  14
```

For visualisation purposes I need to manually interpolate points, i.e. add an intermediate row between each two rows of `df`, where the starting coordinates `x0, y0` are the ending coordinates of original, previous row, while ending coordinates `x1, y1` are the starting coordinates of original, next row. I also need to preserve information if an observation is from original dataset or it is manually added. So the expected output would be:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
      x     y pass_end_x pass_end_y source  
  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>   
1  22.6  62.9       45.8       69.9 original
2  45.8  69.9       38.5       56.6 added   
3  38.5  56.6       49.3       21.9 original
4  49.3  21.9       73.7       27.7 added   
5  73.7  27.7       80.8       14   original
```

How can I do that in efficient and elegant way (preferably in `tidyverse`)?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, all I'm going to do is swap the column names of the start and end points, and then use `lead` to get the next value of `x1` and `y1`. Then we just add the `source` tag, and `bind_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df

names(df2) <- names(df2)[c(3,4,1,2)] # swap names

df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(x1 = lead(x1), y1 = lead(y1),source = "added")

df <- df %>% mutate(source = "original") %>% bind_rows(., df2)
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     x0    y0    x1    y1 source  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1  22.6  62.9  45.8  69.9 original
2  38.5  56.6  49.3  21.9 original
3  73.7  27.7  80.8  14   original
4  45.8  69.9  38.5  56.6 added   
5  49.3  21.9  73.7  27.7 added   
6  80.8  14    NA    NA   added
```

If you need the rows in order:

```
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(x1 = lead(x1), y1 = lead(y1),source = "added", ID = seq(1,n()*2, by =2)+1)

df <- df %>% mutate(source = "original", ID = seq(1,n()*2, by =2)) %>% bind_rows(., df2) %>% arrange(ID)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
     x0    y0    x1    y1 source      ID
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1  22.6  62.9  45.8  69.9 original     1
2  45.8  69.9  38.5  56.6 added        2
3  38.5  56.6  49.3  21.9 original     3
4  49.3  21.9  73.7  27.7 added        4
5  73.7  27.7  80.8  14   original     5
6  80.8  14    NA    NA   added        6
```